# How to check if points are within radius with leaflet/javascript?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a list with 50 items:

```
var mylocations = [{'id':'A', 'loc':[-21,2]},...,];
```

How can I in leaflet or JavaScript most efficiently make it such that if I accept an input of a specific location `[<longitude>,<latitude>]`, a radius (e.g. 50 miles)... I can get all of the `"mylocations"` that fall within that circle?

Using external libraries is fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula

Answer (score 10):

Leaflet's `L.LatLng` objects include a `distanceTo` method:

> Returns the distance (in meters) to the given LatLng calculated using the Haversine formula.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto

```
var inRange = [], latlng_a = new L.LatLng(0, 0), latlng_b;

locations.forEach(function (location) {
    latlng_b_ = new L.LatLng(location.pos[0], location.pos[1]);
    if (latlng_a.distanceTo(latlng_b) < 80.4672) {
        inRange.push(location);
    }
});
```